# Change background color of input text field using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, css, forms, validation

How do I change the background color of a input text field using java script? I want to insert it in a form validation function like this:

```
        function validateForm()
        {
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["username"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
          {
   document.forms["form1"]["username"].style.backgroundColor = Black
          }
        }
```

Also, is there a way to do form validation with php without creating two pages? WHat would you recommend? Using JavaScript or php for validating the user input of a form? I already have a php process form which checks whether the user supplied the correct details like the password etc.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Validation should ALWAYS be done server side.  You can do client side validation too if you like to make things nicer for your users but NEVER trust the data a user sends you it's way too easy to get around client side validation in a browser.

Comment: Thanks, and if i use client-side to handle the user's empty fields and such to highlight the empty field with JS and use server side to handle the pass check. would you suggest using only server side php?

Comment: As for displaying and validating using one page it's easy.  Set the form action to point to itself (don't use a bare [`$PHP_SELF`](http://harrybailey.com/2009/12/using-php_self-safely-and-submitting-forms-to-the-same-page/)!) and then add a hidden form element: `<input type="hidden" name="validate" value="1">`.  Then it's just a mater of an if/else statement `if (isset($_POST['validate'])){/* Process form */} else { /* display form */}`

Comment: No, pointing out empty fields that are required is a valid use of JS, it enhances the user experience. It would be good if the PHP also pointed out empty fields in case someone ignores the JS warnings and submits the form anyway or doesn't have JS turned on.  The point I was trying to make is validate data on the server side before you use it to protect yourself from SQL injection, XSS, etc. Often people just assume that their JS validation protects them from attacks, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the value of the text input. You need to refer to the control itself:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var ctrl = document.forms["form1"]["username"];
    var x=ctrl.value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
       ctrl.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i add it to this line?                                      ////////Change background color///////<br />

Comment: `document.forms["form1"]["username"].style.backgroundColor = color`. In Q: _"how to change background color"_. Not an whole background.

Comment: Yes if you want it there you add it there or wherever you like.

Comment: Would you recommend using jacascript or should i validate it in my process php too? how do you highlight the empty fileds that a user submits using php?

Comment: On the client side you need validation to prevent additional request to the server and show errors to user instantly, but if you have client side validation it's not a reason to remove server side validatio (php). So, the answer: you need both validations, client and server.